# Lubuntu: Apt-Get Can't Find GCC

Tags: apt, lubuntu, gcc

I'm trying to install `gcc` so I can compile the no-ip client. When I try to use `apt-get`, the command returns:

```
unable to locate build-essentials
```

What is the correct `apt-get install package` command to get `gcc`?

Comment: The metapackage name is `build-essential` (singular not plural).

Comment: you dont need build-essential to compile gcc. what does sudo apt-get install gcc  say?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```